# R Parse and select directories with dates

Tags: r, function, parsing, sorting, date

I am new to **R** and trying to create a **R** function that would parse a directory with multiple subdirectories which are named upon time periods. I would like to determine which minimal set of subdirectories could be selected to form a 'continuous' time period.
The function would return a vector of characters that will be used to select the subdirectories of interest.

An example:
suppose that the directory "~" contains the 6 following subdirectories with starting and end dates in a "ddmmyy" format):

```
- "01_231014_190115" 
- "02_231014_190215" 
- "03_190215_200215"
- "04_200215_220215"
- "05_220215_130315" 
- "06_220215_270315"
```

The function would return:

```
"02_231014_190215", "03_190215_200215", "04_200215_220215", "06_220215_270315"
```

I made it until the test to determine, in a clean way, similar start and end dates with this code:

```
foldernames  <- list.files( "~") 
listsplitted <- strsplit(foldernames,"_") 
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(listsplitted), nrow=length(foldernames), byrow=T)) 
colnames(df) <- c("ID","D.start","D.end") 
df[, 2:3]    <- lapply(df[, 2:3], as.Date, format = "%d%m%y",origin="01-01-2000")
df$d.range   <- df[, 3]- df[, 2]
```

which currently returns:

```
> df
  ID    D.start      D.end  d.range
1 01 2014-10-23 2015-01-19  88 days
2 02 2014-10-23 2015-02-19 119 days
3 03 2015-02-19 2015-02-20   1 days
4 04 2015-02-20 2015-02-22   2 days
5 05 2015-02-22 2015-03-13  19 days
6 06 2015-02-22 2015-03-27  33 days
```

I would appreciate a small bit of help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This may be one way of doing it.

Here I created the file_list from your question. But you can get the directory list using the list.dirs() function with recursive = FALSE to prevent listing of sub directories within a directory.

```
#dir_list = list.dirs(path = ".", recursive = FALSE)

dir_list = c("01_231014_190115", "02_231014_190215" , "03_190215_200215", "04_200215_220215", "05_220215_130315" , "06_220215_270315")

df1 <- data.frame(ID = integer(), D.start = character(), D.end = character(), d.range = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

counter = 0

for( i in dir_list){

  counter = counter + 1

  id = as.integer(sub("(.*)(_)(.*)(_)(.*)", '\\1', i))

  start_date = sub("(.*)(_)(.*)(_)(.*)", '\\3', i)

  start_date = as.character(as.Date(start_date, format = "%d%m%y", origin="01-01-2000"))

  end_date = sub("(.*)(_)(.*)(_)(.*)", '\\5', i)

  end_date = as.character(as.Date(end_date, format = "%d%m%y", origin="01-01-2000"))

  df1[counter,1] = id
  df1[counter,2:3] = c(start_date, end_date)
  df1[counter,4] = as.numeric(difftime(end_date, start_date))

}

uniq_start_dates = unique(df1[,2])

df3 <- data.frame(ID = integer(), D.start = character(), D.end = character(), d.range = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(j in uniq_start_dates){

  df2 = df1[which(df1[,2] %in% j), ]

  df3 <- do.call("rbind", list(df3, head(df2[with(df2, order(d.range, decreasing = TRUE)), ], 1)))
}

rm("counter", "id", "end_date", "start_date", "dir_list", "j", "i", "df1", "df2", "uniq_start_dates")
```

Output:

```
print(df1)
  ID    D.start      D.end   d.range
1  1 2014-10-23 2015-01-19  88.04167
2  2 2014-10-23 2015-02-19 119.04167
3  3 2015-02-19 2015-02-20   1.00000
4  4 2015-02-20 2015-02-22   2.00000
5  5 2015-02-22 2015-03-13  18.95833
6  6 2015-02-22 2015-03-27  32.95833

print(df3)
  ID    D.start      D.end   d.range
2  2 2014-10-23 2015-02-19 119.04167
3  3 2015-02-19 2015-02-20   1.00000
4  4 2015-02-20 2015-02-22   2.00000
6  6 2015-02-22 2015-03-27  32.95833
```

Comment: Can you explain "I would like to determine which minimal set of subdirectories could be selected to form a 'continuous' time period"?

Comment: as.Date(as.numeric("270315"), origin = "2000-01-01") will give the date since 2000-01-01 which is "2740-02-06"

Comment: If you just want to format the date, then the origin argument is unnecessary. Eg:  as.Date("270315", format = "%d%m%y") will give "2015-03-27"

Comment: Hi Sathish, thank you for your answers. My apologies if my question was not clear.

Comment: what do you mean by "determine which minimal set of subdirectories"?

Comment: By " I would like to determine which minimal set of subdirectories could be selected to form a 'continuous' time period" I meant so that I can get a reduced number of subdirectories listed, in the range of the oldest date (here 23/10/14) to the newest (27/03/15).

Comment: In the example above, I would like my function to omit directories 1 and 5 as the time period they cover are smaller than those from 2 and 6 respectively.

Comment: this work thank you. I thought we could do it without loops. Cheers